# 31th or 31st is correct?

Tags: orthography, numbers

I just realized that I’ve never needed to use 31th or 31st in my four years English study. So which one is correct, and what about other alternatives?

> 31*th* or 31*st*
>   101*th* or 101*st*
>   1001*th* or 1001*st*

Can I also use that way everywhere in the same way (for example, ordinal numbers in math)?

Comment: Very interesting question, unfortunatelly I believe it is general reference, since single link to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Ordinal_numbers) answers it completely. Also, I would suggest you read it completely, from the way you asked the question I would not bet that you got the numbers up to 30th right. I might be wrong and that's what making this an interesting question (for me).

Comment: @Unreason - Yes, i accept -it's general, but sometimes we really confused because of we're not native speaker and sometimes we need to be sure like this general questions. And look at below, even you guys are not exactly sure just about numbers.. but thanks :)

Comment: This is very interesting question and you are completely right - the answer that you got from MetaEd is better than what is in general reference (it is shorter and does not go inventing rules where the matter can be explained easily). I hope it will not be closed.

Comment: I disagree with those votes to close. The answer to OP's first question (which form is "correct"?) may well be trivial, but the second (what about other alternatives?) isn't - as shown by ["one hundred and oneth"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22one+million+and+oneth%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#pq=%22one+million+and+oneth%22&hl=en&ds=bo&cp=12&gs_id=10&xhr=t&q=%22one+hundred+and+oneth%22&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&newwindow=1&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=%22one+hundred+and+oneth%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5443a9d300c99f37&biw=1137&bih=830&bs=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The OPs question is about ordinal numbers in math, so the 'can I use that way everywhere' is already answered: in math, with constants, you always say the ordinal for '...1' as  '... first'. As to generalizations the answer is mixed and spelled out at [the answers to '(k+1)th or (k+1)st?'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36512/k1th-or-k1st).

Comment: @Mitch: If you want to be picky. But *this* question is closed as "general reference", not because it's a dup of the one you've only just linked to. You could have put that link in yourself earlier - given you've answered the other one I doubt you'd forgotten it. Anyway, I don't think the matter is fully covered there, even though I upvoted Neil and Peter's answers. I still think OP has asked three questions here, and the second should not be closed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There are no other alternatives (or rather, what could the alternatives be?). And put -what- link in earlier? I put the link in here as soon as I found it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the [101st Airborne Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101st_Airborne_Division) *(U.S. Army infantry division trained for air assault)* is a defining case for “standard” usage.

Having said that, in light of [6800 written instances of 101th](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=101th&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) I can’t say the alternative is “wrong”.

Comment: I'd like to see sentences and the context in which you found those written examples... Just because it's been written that way it doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: That's a hot link in the answer. Click on any of the "time period" hotlinks in the chart it leads to, and you'll get a list of specific instances. I know some are rather irrelevant, but there are plenty that exactly cover what we're talking about here. For example, [...successive frames are 97th, 99th and 101th, of which the 101th frame is the current...](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uAZWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22101th%22&dq=%22101th%22&hl=en&ei=-PfLTrqOKYbG8QPWor3mDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y)

Comment: But how would one pronounce 101th? As *one hundred oneth*? Seems like too much of a stretch to me.

Comment: I don't have a problem saying *hundred and oneth* - particularly if I've just been talking about the *hundredth*, and I want to emphasise the increment. Bear in mind I'm not saying it's to be *preferred* - just that quite a few people actually do use this form in certain contexts.

Comment: @onomatomaniak, *one hundred oneth* is exactly how I've (sometimes) heard it. Also, some of those occurrences might be computer-generated: it's much easier to tell a program to tack on a "-th" for all numbers above 3 than to mess around with exceptions or modulo-10 formulas.

Comment: If it had to be pronounced, I would imagine "one-oh-oneth". Although that still sounds awkward.

Comment: @Martha: Thanks for pointing out the relevance of "dumb computer code", but I doubt that applies to many of the written instances I linked to.

Comment: @Marthaª Interesting. I've never heard that before.

Comment: I agree with Onomatomaniak, it's too much of a stretch to pronounce 101th. Is it possible that the writer got carried away while writing and wrote 101th by mistake? I know it's sheer speculation, but it does sound unnatural.

Comment: Differences are "[One] hundred and first" for 101st and "One-oh-oneth" for 101th.  I've seen and used it both ways before..

Comment: @Irene: [Here's](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22million+and+oneth%22&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&prmd=imvns&ei=AyrMTsyUHMng8gOmj5jEDw&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5443a9d300c99f37&biw=1137&bih=830) a couple of dozen written instances of **one million and oneth**. I honestly don't think a single one of them would be the writer getting "carried away", or being ignorant of "standard practice". It may not be the norm, but writers do sometimes use this form quite deliberately.

Comment: @Martha: I'm starting to feel like a dog with a bone on this one... NGram has only a single written instance of *one hundred oneth*, and none at all for *one-oh-oneth*. But it does have 102 results for *one hundred* **and** *oneth* (I'm not even going to look for *...tooth* or *...threeth!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm not surprised you're not finding many results for "oneth" - in contexts where you're spelling out numbers, you're much more likely to write it as "first".

Comment: @Martha: I don't think there's any disagreement about what we're *much more likely to write.* The issue to me is when and why people *sometimes* opt for non-standard "oneth", which they clearly never do with "twoth?!" or "threeth".

Comment: @Fumble: But they do: wiktionary has a definition for *threeth*, and you can find several results with a simple Google search (mostly jocular).  That, in a nutshell, is why I object to "any word that is used is good English"; it deprives 'good English' of meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What would be the successor to the nth thing, if not the n-plus-oneth?

Comment: @supercat: You're asking *me?* My answer is the only one out of the three here that *doesn't* claim the rules are "absolute". But seriously, I don't think *n-plus-oneth* is a potentially contentious form. It deconstructs in the mind of the speaker as (n+1)th because there's no reason to expect the actual value of (n+1) will end in the digit 1. If, on the other hand, you always spoke in contexts where n could *only* be 10, 20, 30,...90, I can believe you might be tempted to call its successor the "nth-ty-first".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Awhile ago, I was thinking of n-plus-oneth when trying to identify rhymes for "month".  So far as I know, there isn't really any other plausible rhyme for "month", whereas "orange" has "door hinge", and "purple" has "her pull".

Comment: @supercat: There's [kunth](http://www.wordnik.com/words/Kunth) *a nitrogen fixing tree that is commonly grown as an ornamental.*

Answer (score 36):

The numerals with endings are merely abbreviations for the words written out as text. When in doubt, write the word out. Thirty-fir*st* becomes 31*st*, eleven*th* 11*th*, forty-seco*nd* 42*nd*, fiftie*th* 50*th*, and so on.

Comment: Thank you +1, this is what I wanted to say. It is incredibly interesting that even wikipedia needs to define set of rules when rule is so simple.

Answer (score 14):

*31st*, etc. are the correct options. When you use ordinal numbers ending in 1, you use *first*. The only exception is *eleventh*, because although it ends in 1 its “name” doesn’t contain the word “one” like 21, 31, etc.

Comment: What about dates? 41st or 41th of February is correct?

Comment: The only exception seems to be 11: *Eleventh* (11th) is correct, but *Elevenst* (11st) is not.

Comment: @dinobeytar: If February *had* 41 days (it doesn't), then it would be *41st of February*.

Comment: Irene's explanation holds up for dates as well.  There are also rules for numbers ending in 2 and 3 - use nd for 2 - 2nd, 748392nd; rd for 3 - 3rd, 38743rd.  When dealing with teens these do not apply - 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th all the way to 19th are correct.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: You're right about 11th. I should have included it. Thanks for pointing it out and completed my answer.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Haha... Sometimes my brain just stop to work.. But, anyway..

Comment: 11th isn't the only exception:  What about 12th (2nd, 22nd..) and 13th (3rd, 23rd..) _EDIT_ Brainfart, I see Mohandas said basically the same thing