# How to read (x - y) ^ 2

Tags: mathematics

I don't know how to read this expression:

> (x-y)<sup>2</sup> — sometimes rendered in computer code or plain text as (x-y)^2

According to this answer:
[How to read x^y](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/how-to-read-exponential-expressions-e-g-216/76680#76680)

I should read that: `x minus y to the power of two`
But I'm not sure it's the way that native people read it; And I don't know how to mention parentheses.

Comment: I would use _the quantity of..._, otherwise it sounds like only _y_ is squared.

Comment: @Cascabel I don't know what that mean and I think it still doesn't convey parantheses.

Comment: "The quantity of x minus y, squared." _quantity of_ implies parentheses.

Comment: You can say *ex minus wye, squared*. This one is prone to be confused with x-y^2. You can say *the square of ex minus wye*. Even though there is no pause in this one for some reason people don't confuse it as much with x^2-y. It seems that people expect a longer pause before *minus* when calling x^2-y as *the square of ex, minus wye*.

Comment: Another way to say it is to say what is in parentheses, then add "quantity squared". The fact is that any real mathematics has to be worked with in writing. Mathematics is not intended to be pronounced for the most part, and these rules only work for simple expressions like this. Imagine how one might pronounce Maxwell's equations, for instance.

Comment: There are many ways to express it, one of them is "the difference between x and y, squared" where "difference" is result of subtraction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The quantity x minus y, all squared."

Commenters have suggested using "quantity" to indicate that x-y is a single expression. I suggest saying "all squared" as a reminder of that.

(Source: mathematician and educator who says/hears this often.)

*Edit:* I'll add some more thoughts to make this answer more complete and simultaneously address a few comments.

Ultimately, there is not one conventionally "correct" way of reading such an expression out loud or in one's own mind. The goal here is to convey the concept of taking two numbers, which are called x and y, finding the difference x minus y, and then squaring that result. Indeed, mathematical notation is created to fill that purpose! We use the expression (x-y)^2 to mean exactly that idea I just described in words, and this expression will always be unambiguously interpreted in that way.

So, when someone asks, "How do I read that expression out loud?" or "How do I say that expression in my head when I'm reading it in a book?", they are asking for a way to translate that expression from *mathematical language* into *natural language*, and this may introduce ambiguities. In some sense, the "correct" way to write/read this expression is the one that is in mathematical language: (x-y)^2  There is not one officially correct way to translate this into natural language. Rather, the best thing to do is to say/write anything that will be interpreted unambiguously as that expression. I suggested "the quantity x minus y, all squared" because I am confident that 100% of my colleagues and students would read those words in natural language and translate them into (x-y)^2 in mathematical language.

Someone suggested "the quantity of x minus y" instead, and this is not really more or less correct in any way. It is just different. I am also confident that my colleagues and students would interpret that as (x-y), but I also suspect that some of them (like me) would bristle a little at the "of", not because it's wrong but because it just sounds redundant and unnecessary. Although, if I were keeping track of how I say out loud what I suggested, I would probably go, "The quantity [short pause] x minus y [short pause] all squared". I suspect the suggested "of" is analogous to the brief pause I would use when saying this out loud.

But ultimately, I hope this sheds more light on these ideas and why I think my answer is best.

Comment: While we usually require sources, a simple [search to your bio](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/289058/brendan-w-sullivan) reveals that you should be an authority on this. Do not be shy. However, this still seems like a partial answer...

Comment: Just to be sure: would you say, “The quantity x minus y”, or was there supposed to be an _of_ in there?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I would say "The quantity x minus y". If I heard "The quantity OF x minus y", I would interpret it the same way, but it just "sounds funny" for some reason. I suspect others would say the same.

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan My instinct is the exact opposite, but I know just a tad less than nothing at all about maths, so I will trust your instinct as being far more reliable than mine here. :-)

Comment: I think that this is gonna turn out as John L. commented.. I only taught maths in High School in another country, and as you can imagine, things may have gone a little squirrely...nevertheless, in the books I taught out of (all USA curriculum for the South East whatever they called it) they had it as _the quantity of_...maybe they were just being pedantic.

Comment: I've always heard it as *The quantity "x minus y" squared*  (using quotation marks to reflect intonational isolation -- to indicate that the quantity is being referred to "by name" i.e. by its identifier).  No "of".  And no "all". https://books.google.com/books?id=BJWdAAAAMAAJ&q=%22the+quantity+x+plus+2+squared%22&dq=%22the+quantity+x+plus+2+squared%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaisebpKjgAhV0H7kGHbSpAowQ6AEIKTAA

Comment: @Cascabel: Thanks :-) I just added some thoughts so this is no longer a partial answer.

Comment: Interesting: there was a different way of saying this aloud in the Australian university classes I attended. For a simple expression like this, we wouldn't say "quantity", it would just be "x minus y, all squared" (the comma is deliberate, as there's a slight pause). For a different exponent, we'd replace "all squared" with "all to the power *n*". For a longer expression, we'd use the clunky "open brackets, three x squared minus seven y plus z, close brackets, all to the power n plus 1". For even longer expressions, we'd say "see what's written".

Comment: @Chappo: I think of "quantity" as just another way of indicating where the open and closed brackets are. As I said in my answer, as long as it ultimately makes it obvious what is intended, then it can be considered "correct". And yes, sometimes the best answer is just, "Look at how it's written."

Comment: Yes, I think that's the most critical point: if spoken aloud, it must avoid the possibility of ambiguity, so that each operation is performed on the correct operand(s). Even lazy cops approach things one operation at a time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> (x-y)^2 — sometimes rendered in computer code or plain text as (x-y)^2

If I was reading this out loud to somebody I would say

> x minus y in brackets squared.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to read (x - y)^2 as

> Ex minus wye quantity squared

when I was studying algebra in high school and continued to hear it read that way by math professors in college. Of course, *squared* is a special case where the power is 2. In the general case of (x - y)^n I was taught to read that as

> Ex minus wye quantity, to the power en

I'm not saying other ways of reading it are wrong, I am saying that in math and engineering classes I took in high school and college, that was the convention that I was taught and other people used.

For *much* greater detail, see the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35496/29642) (and the references they link to). In particular, see [this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Efateman/papers/speakmath.pdf) which explicitly recommends speaking ( a + b ) / ( c + d ) as

> a plus b quantity over quantity c plus d

The paper also considers all of these phrases acceptable for x^3:

> x to the the third
>
> x to the third power
>
> x to the power 3
>
> x raised to the power 3
>
> x cubed

Answer (score -2):

"(x-y)^2"

I would say x-y (parenthesis) times x-y (parenthesis), since this expression means (x-y) * (x-y). (pronouncing parenthesis is optional!)

Then the terms inside the parenthesis are multiplied term by term. You get:
x^2 -xy -xy + y^2  which gives us :

x^2  -2xy  + y^2 as the answer!

Comment: There are two reasons why this answer is wrong. Firstly, "x minus y times itself" is actually `x - y*y`, which is **not** the same. Secondly, `^2` doesn't mean "times itself", even though that is the logical outcome. It *means* "(raised) to the exponent 2" or "to the power 2". Your solution would be meaningless if the exponent were 3, or *n*, or (2n+1).