# How do you say "powers of ten"?

Tags: speech, mathematics

When you have ***[powers of](https://www.britannica.com/science/power-of-10)*** 10, e.g.  10<sup>2</sup>,  the base is 10, so when the exponent is 2 you should not say *power of 2*. I believe "power of" refer to the base not to the exponent.

Comment: Whether it's "power" or "powers" depends on the context, not the base.

Comment: *Power* in *to the power of* refers to the exponent as a location or role, which is also called exponent. This is only one for the operation denoted by 10^2: *ten to the power of two*. In *powers of ten*, the word *powers* refers to the collection of results obtained by raising ten to the different integer exponents.

Comment: Every base is base 10.

Comment: What context do you need this in? If I understand you correctly there’s no concise idiom because there isn’t much reason (mathematically) to speak of “things raised to the nth power” as a unit, in the same way as we speak of “powers of n”: the mathematical series “powers of n” has important properties and connections to fundamental laws in mathematics. The series “things raised to the nth power” does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read exponential expressions, e.g., "2^16"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/how-to-read-exponential-expressions-e-g-216)

Comment: The example 10 exp 2 is not a good example, because the usual way to express that is 10 squared.  10 exp 3 is 10 cubed.  Avogadro's Number is, on the other hand, 6.03 times 10 to the 23rd.   As for every base being base 10, often the base is e (2.71828.....); sometimes the base is 2.  The base can be anything,

Comment: @PieterB: Ha! Good one.

Comment: @ab2 6.022  or round down, 6.02. Not 3. Huge difference when multiplying by 10^23.  :)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer  Thanks!  My memory is failing me......:)

Comment: @ab2 "Every base is base 10" was a joke. How do you write 2 in base 2? You write 10.

Comment: "I believe ... ." When communicating, it's not very important what you believe the words you say mean; what really matters is what _other_ people believe they mean.

Comment: @David K  Blush.

Answer (score 20):

I express 3^4 as “three to the fourth power”

You can say “base to the nth power” or “base to the power of n”

It’s important to have the whole sentence to determine if it makes mathematical sense.

Comment: This works for integers n, but what if we get real? 3^e or 3^π? Three to the pieth power?

Comment: @JJJ - well I did say “base to the power of n”... you can replace n as you wish .

Comment: Ah yeah that works. ;)

Comment: @JJJ It's also common to drop the "*th* power", and just say "*base* to the *n*", e.g "ten to the two is one hundred", or ["e to the i pi is minus one"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity)

Comment: @Chronocidal very well, though I'd say it's a bit weird to write the *i* before the π in your example (though that may just be me).

Comment: @JJJ Eh, blame Euler for that one.  Normally you *would* put the imaginary unit after the scalar

Comment: @JJJ Even "base to the power of e" is common enough.

Comment: @user45266 - yes, I literally wrote exactly that.

Comment: Sorry, @JoeTaxpayer, I made a few mistakes, one of which was not tagging, the other being that I meant e instead of n.

Comment: @Chronocidal - "Ten to the two" would get you strange looks in many quarters.

Comment: @user45266 - I'm thinking a mod can kill the comments loading here. Their call.

Answer (score 20):

While "ten to the power of two" is correct (and the "power" does indeed refer to the "two" *in this construction*), it's also possible and very common to drop the "power of", giving "ten to the two".  When reading out vacuum pressures for example, "ten to the power of minus six" would never be heard from a native speaking physicist; we'd just say "ten to the minus six".  This is equally true in longer constructions like "three point five times ten to the minus seven".

Comment: It would generally be "to the minus sixth", or "10 to the 23rd".

Comment: @jamesqf not IME. I rarely hear positive ordinals used in this case for magnitudes, and never negative ordinals, unless followed by "power" (UK here). Also never "second", even "second power" - "squared" is occasional.  When I say never I mean not once in my recollection in two physics departments and an engineering firm; I have a vague recollection that some of the older academics did use ordinals for magnitudes in the 90s. In formulae (x^5) cardinals are still  more common but ordinals familiar - again only positive ones.

Comment: @jamesqf I've never heard using ordinal numbers for negative powers: "ten to the third", but "ten to the minus three" (and I work in a field where powers of ten are fairly common).

Comment: @jamesqf "ten to the twenty-third *power*", or "ten to the twenty-three" - but not normally "ten to the twenty-third".  So, "ten to the third" is `10^⅓`, not `10^3`

Comment: I disagree with @Chronocidal ... "ten to the third" means 10^3.

Comment: 10^⅓ would be "ten to the *one* third" if it was unavoidable (@Chronocidal) and 10^3 could just about be "ten to the third" but "ten to the three" is more common

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano: I agree that sometimes it's cardinals with negative powers, but usually only for small powers. Seems to shift around -10.  I don't recall ever hearing other than ordinals for positive exponents (other than "squared" or "cubed") - and I do have education/career in science.

Comment: @Chronocidal: No, 10^⅓ would be "ten to the one-third", at least as I would say it.  10^3 would most likely be "ten cubed", possibly "ten to the third", never "ten to the three".

Comment: @jamesqf where are you (if you don't mind me asking), because there seems to be a difference in actual use that may be regional - as I commented, cardinals seem to be the norm in my UK experience, with the exceptions being older

Comment: @Chris H: Western US, mostly, with a couple years working with a research group in Switzerland.  So indeed it might be a British/American difference.

Answer (score 12):

The term **power** refers to the exponent, not to the base.

> 10 to the **power** 2 is 100.

However **powers** of 10 are the products obtained from raising 10 by various exponents. So again, **power** does not refer to the base.

Comment: also **power** *of* 2 sometimes

Comment: I always hear this phrased with ordinals rather than cardinals.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor **Power of 2** refers to binary arithmetic and means 2 raised to some power. Whenever we say "a power of _n_" we mean _n_ raised to some power, that _n_ is the base. The second power of 2 is 2x2 which is 4, the third power of 2 is 2x2x2 which is 8 and so on. Similarly the second power of 8 is 64.

Comment: @chrylis Both cardinals and ordinals are fine for integer and simple variable powers, "x to the sixth power", "x to the nth power" and "x to the power n" are all absolutely acceptable. However if you need to use negative, fractional or irrational powers then ordinals rapidly become clumsy. "n to the power minus two upon three" or "x to the power pi" are much clearer than "n to the minus two-third-th power" or "x to the pi-th power".

Comment: @chrylis that may be so but how would you say 10^0? It can be the same with percentages. Some people say "the 5th centile/percentile" but it gets tricky for a non-integer value such as 1.5 and in this case the more usual "1.5 percent" works better. The question however is about the use of the word **power** rather than whether cardinal or ordinal numbers are be used to express them.

Comment: "Ten to the zeroth power."

Answer (score 5):

A common expression for power(s) of 10 in regular speech is **order(s) of magnitude**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude):

> An order of magnitude is an approximate measure of the number of digits that a number has in the commonly-used base-ten number system. It is equal to the logarithm (base 10) rounded to a whole number. For example, the order of magnitude of 1500 is 3, because 1500 = 1.5 × 10^3.

Comment: be careful as some fields consider powers of 2 to be orders of magnitude.

Comment: @james could you give some examples of "powers of 2 = orders of magnitude" please?  As a physicist (and formerly engineer) with a fair bit of software  background and even some knowledge of bus-level data transport and machine code I've never come across this use.

Comment: @ChrisH Well for one, SI units use orders of magnitude of base 1000, another is IEC prefixes which use orders of magnitude of base 1024 (admittedly can't think of any that use base 2 though). If I talk about an order of magnitude larger than MiB I don't think 10s of MiB, I think GiB

Comment: @NickA the second of those is possible, but the in usual use of "order of magnitude" 1000=1024 anyway (if I say my new hard drive is 3 orders of magnitude bigger than my old one, whether I'm referring to GiB and TiB or GB and TB is irrelevant).  So 2^10 is 3 orders of magnitude, fine. But james didn't say that, instead implying something more like  an order of magnitude means a doubling

Comment: @ChrisH Yes sorry, I corrected myself on the GB/GiB, force of habit. I also see now you weren't arguing that others aren't valid, but base 2 specifically :), which I agree with. Although I would call 2^10 one order of magnitude rather than 3 (speaking in the context of where it makes sense)

Comment: @NickA further, the SI handbook, which I have in front of me, is perfectly happy with cm (it lists prefixes for 10^±1 and 10^±2 before the sequence of 10^3n).  Ah OK, it sounds like we're not far apart.

Comment: @ChrisH True, and I can't imagine (in terms of orders of magnitude) anything being more confusing than cm=-2, dm=-1, m=0, dam=1, hm=2, km=3, Mm=4..., So I retract the SI units one, although IEC applies :) (da and h I'd never heard of before now...)

Comment: Also, the magnitude of a star is the negative logarithm of its brightness (the idea is that the magnitude measures how big of a telescope you need to see it).

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, this is explained fairly well on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Terminology).

> I believe "power of" refer to the base not to the exponent

Nope. The spoken forms of 10<sup>2</sup> are:

- 10 raised to the second power, *or*
- 10 raised to the power of two, *or*
- 10 to the power of two, *or*
- 10 to the two, *or simply*
- 10 squared

Since the original formulation *base raised to the nth power* means *multiply 1 by base n times*, the word *power* does indeed refer to the exponent.

Comment: "Raised" and "of" are optional in your examples. E.g., "x to the power y" is completely normal in mathematical English.

Comment: I think I'd usually omit the "power" as well in that case, but pretty much any combination seems acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

"Powers of 10" does definitely refer to power expressions with 10 as a base rather than as an exponent. I don't have any sourced explanation (which makes this a terrible answer), but I imagine it's because of the similarity between the two phrases

- 10 raised to the second power
- the second power of 10

Answer (score 2):

The expression *a power of 10* typically means the number you get when you raise 10 to a power (exponent, in other words) which itself is a number. I know it's a little bit confusing since you refer to the result of raising a number to a power also as a power, but that's just how people say it. Thus, you can say that the following is a list of powers of 10, that is, a list of the numbers you get when you raise 10 to a particular power such as 1, 2, 3, etc:

> 10<sup>1</sup> = 10
>   10<sup>2</sup> = 100
>   10<sup>3</sup> = 1000
>   etc.

Given the fact that the numbers 10<sup>2</sup> and 100 are equivalent, they both can be referred to as a power of ten. More specifically, it's *ten raised to the second power* or more compactly *ten to the second power*. Likewise, 10<sup>8</sup> would be pronounced *ten to the eighth power* or *ten raised to the eighth power*.

Usually, for powers that are greater than 3, you can drop the word "power". For example, instead of saying *ten to the eighth power*, you can just say *ten to the eighth*.

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, 10^2  is often called "10 to the power of 2"; but as others have noted, the "öf"is redundant, and strictly incorrect.  As you suggest, it is better to keep the phrase "power of" to refer to the base; and say "10 to the power 2", or just "10 to the 2".