# Do we have to use ordinals with largest/smallest?

Tags: numbers, mathematics, ordinal-numbers

In every-day language, I would say, "Give me the fifth largest pumpkin you have"; that is I would use the ordinal.

However, this feels [clunky](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36512/k1th-or-k1st) in mathematical texts, especially when reading out loud: "select the k-th largest element" or, even worse, "the k plus first/oneth largest element".

Is it fair to say/write "the k-largest element"? It seems to me that the "aspect of ordinality" is sufficiently expressed by the -st suffix in larger (or smallest, heaviest, ...), that is the superlative.

Comment: Note that there is a typographic dimension here, too; `$k$th largest` just looks weird, whereas `$k$-largest` (do we want/need the hyphen?) works.

Comment: Note that MathJax doesn't work on ELU. However *k*th-largest is probably acceptable. You may need a hairspace between *k* and "th".

Comment: k-th largest is acceptable. But this is probably better answered by those in that mathematical specialty. [See math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=kth)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know, that's why I used code formatting. ;) The looks of mixing the math font (italic) with text (upright) specifically annoys me, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Mitch I'm sure I'd get all kinds of "what I prefer" answers; I wanted the perspective of experts of the English language, specifically.

Comment: I was suggesting that the better judges of acceptability would be the experts in mathematical English, rather than those here. You'd get any 'what I prefer' here as well as there equally. Use "the $k$-th largest element", not $k$ largest, that's how it is said.

Answer (score 7):

Consider this situation where you could write your request as

> Give me the 5th largest sheep

or

> Give me the 5 largest sheep

They obviously mean completely different things.  One will result in you having a sheep, the other in you having five sheep.  Hence you should stick to the *kth* convention.

Comment: Of course you pick a deliberately confusing example. The use case I have in mind is with the proper noun "element(s)" (no confusion), and all other use cases in my context I can imagine are unproblematic as well. Also, my proposal was "5-largest", not "5 largest" (I think the difference is crucial, for the reasons you state). Note furthermore that it won't be *kth* but *k* th, and I state that the mixture of fonts is one of the reason of my asking. So in all, thanks, but this does not help me. :/

Comment: The mixture of fonts is not mentioned in your question.  In addition, the "aspect of ordinality" is not sufficiently expressed by means of the superlative, as it took me about 2 seconds to think of an example that would break your attempt at creating a new convention.  Mathematicians are perfectly happy saying things like "kth" and "k-plus-oneth" simply because they are unambiguous.  Mathematicians deliberately eschew ambiguity, hence I repeat that you should not try to create a new convention.
Incidentally, "*k*th" is perfectly fine too, as far as the mathematician in me is concerned.

Comment: Another option is to use "*n*" instead of "*k"", as you will find that "nth" is well used, and even documented in English dictionaries, as well as mathematical glossaries.