# How do ordinal suffixes work with mathematical constants and other non-Arabic numbers?

Tags: numbers, mathematics, ordinal-numbers

This question was inspired by a tweet from the FakeUnicode Twitter account, a semi-novelty account sharing various examples in the wild of bugs, glitches and other unintended results from improperly implementing the Unicode character encoding standard.

> What are the English ordinal suffixes of various mathematical constants and concepts? Is it always -th?
>
> πᵗʰ
>   ᵗʰ
>   ℎᵗʰ
>   ᵗʰ
>   φᵗʰ
>   ∞ᵗʰ
>   ℵ₀ᵗʰ
>   ₆₄ᵗʰ
>
> [Try saying these aloud for extra fun]
>   <sub>source: https://twitter.com/FakeUnicode/status/1086205723736854528</sub>

How does the English language decline ordinal suffixes for numbers that are displayed in a different way than an Arabic number?

Comment: This would be used with an ordinal, but it could be a symbol, like your example *h*.  And note! For something like $n+1$ you have to add "st" not "th".

Comment: @GEdgar I can't agree with your note. The element n+1 of a series is the n+1th element. This is because , as the value of n is a variable, the number which is suffixed is (n+1) and the ordinal for (n+1) is (n+1)th. For example if n=21 then the n+1th element is the 22nd, if n= 27 the n+1th element is the 28th. Only elements whose number is known can have any suffix other than 'th' because it is the most general.

Comment: I just count "oneth, tooth, threeth, forth, fifeth ..." and be done with it!

Comment: In Lojban it's easy. 'moi' can be added after any numeral string.

Comment: Just a note: using ordinal suffixes for things other ordinal concepts is not standard. A πᵗʰ element of a list doesn't really have a next or previous element (and if you want to make a case for that, best over at math.SE). We can talk all day about unicorn, unicorns, unicornized, unicornically, but  talking about them don't make them actual things. Except being ghosted; that's just not nice.

Comment: Related question about [k+1th or k+1st](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36512/k1th-or-k1st).

Comment: Another link about [k+1th vs k+1st](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55200/k1th-k1st-k-th1-or-k1). End result? No consensus, people do both.

Comment: Ordinals apply to integers, thus most of Nzall's list is nonsense.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The counterexample on the Twitter thread is taking the *n*th root of a number, where *n* is *π*, *e*, *i*, &c.; and indeed I would use *-th* for that, pronounced *-eth* in at least some circumstances, like *hth* /ˈeɪtʃ.ɪθ/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English orthography, there are four [ordinal indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator): *st, nd, rd* for 1, 2, and 3, and *th* for all the rest, including variables or unreal numbers. Writing the indicator as a superscript, with or without underlining, derives from the practice of Latin scribes.

This is an orthographic convention only loosely connected to the spoken language: whether you can actually pronounce the result, or, when able, you sound like you have a severe lisp, is irrelevant.

One such construction escaped mathematical jargon about as soon as there were enough educated speakers to know what it meant:

> …here was beauty—and art—developed to the n’th degree, perfumes, the delicate swish of silk, a being that his arms ached for—and that day passionately clasped.  — Gilbert Parker, “The Empty Cruse,” *Aspen Evening Chronicle* (CO), 23 Mar. 1893.

More contemporary writers simply use *nth*:

> An almost entirely black canvas takes the black square of Malevich to the nth degree. — *LA Downtown News*, 10 Apr. 2017.

One suspects that had *nth* yielded as absurd a pronunciation as some of your examples, it never would have made the leap from the classroom into popular language.