# When defining the median for an odd number of measurements, should we use [(n+1)/2]th or [(n+1)/2]nd?

Tags: mathematics, ordinal-numbers

When defining the median for an odd number of measurements, should we use  [(n+1)/2]th or [(n+1)/2]nd?

I am aware of a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36512/k1th-or-k1st) but I am nor sure if having the number 2 in the denominator makes a difference.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments. Write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An educational article from the relevant [Singapore Government Agency website](https://stats.mom.gov.sg/SL/Pages/Median-Concepts-and-Definitions.aspx) has

> ' ... the (n+1)/2 -th term'

and I'm sure other texts will follow this practice (though I'd prefer the th as a superscript and without the hyphen).

This surely reflects how one would pronounce this when necessary (though I think I got away with two times per A-Level Maths cohort).

Comment: But if you superscript it, then it looks like you're raising 2 to the *th*-th power.

Comment: If you don't, it looks like the denominator is (2 - th) {or 2th if you omit the hyphen). The superscript is the lesser of two evils.